# benchmarking requests to localhost

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking, multiprocessing, python-requests

I am writing a benchmarking tool from scratch in Python.
However I can't get the performance of other benchmarking tools like `wrk` or `wrk2`. Using wr2 I can make 42k requests/s while my code can only create up to 2200 reqs/s. I have tried multiple ways to parallelize the code execution. I have tried using multiprocessing and parallel computing libraries like [Dask](https://tutorial.dask.org/00_overview.html). But I can't get better performance. I understand `wrk` and `wrk2` are written in C which can be one reason but still 42k vs 2200 seems like a very large difference.

I have tried with different number of workers and `number_of_request`, but the performance does not change much.

I am trying to understand if I am really hitting the upper limit or I am doing something wrong. The server is running on localhost and written in Java Spring.

This is my code using multiprocessing:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import requests

# import multiprocessing as mp

num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()  


output = multiprocessing.Queue()
def runner(number_of_request):
    output=""
    for i in range(number_of_request):
        try:
            output+=str(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/").text)
        except:
            pass
        # print(output)
    
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_request = 1000
    start = time.time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_workers)
    outputs = [pool.apply_async(runner, args = (number_of_request,)) for x in range(num_workers)]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    duration = time.time() - start 
    req_s = (number_of_request*num_workers)/duration
    print("duration =", time.time() - start)
    print(req_s)
```

Comment: Bit hard to compare two ways if we see only one of them.

Comment: To anyone in the close vote queue, code that is working as expected but not performing well is a good question for code review, this question does not belong in the close vote queue.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/259847/4) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Performance notwithstanding, there's some other cleanup that's worth doing:

- Capitalize `NUM_WORKERS` since it's a global constant
- Do not shadow your global `output` with a local variable of the same name; and ideally don't have a global `output` at all
- After your `get()` and before your call to `.text`, you need to check whether the request succeeded - either via `.ok` and a log entry showing the reason; or by `.raise_for_status()`
- *never* `try / except / pass`. This is the broadest and most dangerous form of silent exception-swallowing. If `runner` is executing and the user attempts to terminate the application with a Ctrl+C, that will be ignored here, and all other error information has become invisible to you. Consider at least `except Exception:` and logging the exception using the standard logging framework.
- Consider annotating `runner` as `def runner(number_of_requests: int) -> str`
- Do not cast the result of `.text` to a string - it's already a string
- Do not use `time.time()` here; instead use `time.perf_counter()` for a sufficiently short duration or `time.monotonic()` otherwise
- The parens in `(number_of_request*num_workers)/duration` are redundant